# What is the right way to subset timeseries data in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I loaded timeseries for COVID-19 that has data for all the counties in the US.
[timeseries data for COVID-19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQLlW.png)

I then created separate data frames for the counties that I am interested in based on 'fips'.
[Subset data based on counties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nILGm.png)

However, when I add the 'deaths' column across these two counties, I don't get the correct sum (I have replaced NaN with 0s). I have tried

```
County_Data_Dallas['deaths'] + County_Data_Tarrant['deaths']
```

And

```
Sum_Deaths=County_Data_Dallas['deaths'].add(County_Data_Tarrant['deaths'])
```

Comment: the sum is made based on the index

Comment: Are you trying to get a sum of all deaths in both counties?

Comment: "Are you trying to get a sum of all deaths in both counties?"
Yes, exactly.

Comment: "the sum is made based on the index"
I tried to reindex the county specific dataframes but that wasn't helpful. Either I am not subsetting it correctly (why are new data frames created from the original one holding on to original indexing?), or I need to figure out how to index based on date column.